# Postgres function as column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two functions in Postgesql database:

- `id_generator`, which generates id from timestamp
- `timestamp_from_id(id)`, which reverses id to timestamp

Let's assume this is my model:

```
class DatModel(object):
    id = Column(
        BigInteger,
        primary_key=True,
        server_default=text('id_generator()')
    )
    name = Column(String(50), index=True)
```

What I want to do is query by `timestamp` generated by `timestamp_from_id(id)` function, for example:

```
dbsession.query(DatModel).filter(DatModel.timestamp > datetime.now()).all()
```

or

```
obj = dbsession.query(DatModel).first()
created = obj.timestamp
```

**My question is:**

How to create virtual column based on postgres function?

Thanks in advance

---

Edit:

#### Unsatisfying method #1

As [Roman Dryndik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2177538/roman-dryndik) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413433/1338790) possible solution is to use [func](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func). It's working method, but little problematic way while retrieving timestamp:

```
timestamp = session.execute(func.timestamp_from_id(obj.id)).fetchone()
```

I'd prefer to do it something like:

```
timestamp = obj.timestamp
```

#### Unsatisfying method #2

Second possible solution is to use [Compilation Extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html?highlight=compiles#sqlalchemy.ext.compiler.compiles)

```
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import FunctionElement

class Timestamp(FunctionElement):
    type = DateTime()
    name = 'timestamp'

@compiles(Timestamp)
def default_timestamp(element, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_function(element)

@compiles(Timestamp, 'postgresql')
def pg_created(element, compiler, **kw):
    arg1 = list(element.clauses)[0]
    return 'timestamp_from_id({})'.format(compiler.process(arg1))


# filter example
obj = session.query(DatModel).filter(Timestamp < datetime.now()).first()

# get timestamp attribute example
timestamp = session.execute(Timestamp(obj.id)).fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `hybrid_property` and `expression` ([docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior))

```
class DatModel(Base)::
    id = Column(
        BigInteger,
        primary_key=True,
        server_default=text('id_generator()')
    )

    @hybrid_property
    def timestamp(self):
        return object_session(self). \
            scalar(select([func.timestamp_from_id(self.id)]))

    @created.expression
    def timestamp(self):
        return func.timestamp_from_id(self.id)
```

Example usage:

```
obj = DatModel()
with transaction.manager:
    session.add(obj)
obj = session.query(DatModel).one()

assert type(obj.timestamp) == datetime.datetime
assert obj.timestamp.date() == datetime.date.today()


objs = session.query(DatModel) \
    .filter(DatModel.timestamp < datetime.datetime.now())
assert objs.count() == 1

objs = session.query(Gateway) \
    .filter(DatModel.timestamp > datetime.datetime.now())
assert objs.count() == 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Please read [Using `column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) section of *SQL Expressions as Mapped Attributes* documentation.

Using it you should be able to do:

```
class DatModel(Base):
    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        server_default=text('id_generator()')
    )
    name = Column(String(50), index=True)

    timestamp = column_property(func.timestamp_from_id(id))
```

`timestamp` will also be included in your query, and you can use it in the filtering and/or ordering expressions:

```
q = (session.query(DatModel)
     .filter(DatModel.timestamp > datetime.now())
     .order_by(DatModel.timestamp.desc())
    )
```

Comment: It is possible, that solution works, but not for me. I have mixin model and column property gave me an error: 
```InvalidRequestError: Mapper properties (i.e. deferred,column_property(), relationship(), etc.) must be declared as @declared_attr callables on declarative mixin classes.```

But it lead me to the right solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem you can call the stored procedure `timestamp_from_id` using `func`.

So you will get something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# some code here

dbsession.query(DatModel).filter(func.timestamp_from_id(DataModel.id) > datetime.now()).all()

# some code here
```

Didn't try the code. Probably you should do `func.timestamp_from_id(DataModel.id).scalar()` as well.

More info you can find [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/wYVVKcQTmPk).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a [column_property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) with a [literal_column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column). For example:

```
class DatModel(object):
    id = Column(
        BigInteger,
        primary_key=True,
        server_default=text('id_generator()')
    )
    name = Column(String(50), index=True)
    timestamp = column_property(literal_column("timestamp_from_id(datmodel.id)", type_=DateTime).label('timestamp'))
```